# Create a simple line editor

Tags: code-golf, string, interactive

**In:** a string without line breaks*
**Allow the user to edit and submit the line**
**Out:** the modified string (optionally with a trailing linebreak)

The line editor must at minimum allow the user to:

1. move a visible cursor left and right
2. insert and/or overwrite characters at the cursor position
3. remove characters at the cursor position
4. submit the new string, i.e. cease editing cause the modified string to be returned/printed/displayed/saved… (with no other text)

Appreciated, but not required:

- explanation of your code.
- link to an online testing site that can demonstrate your program/function
- an animated image demonstrating usage (TIO, for instance, does not allow interactivity)

Note:

- key-bindings are suggestions only
- GUI or visual styling is not required

#### Examples

In the following, the cursor is illustrated with `_`.

**In:** `Just some text`
**Allow the user to edit:**
 <kbd>`Just some text_`</kbd>   User presses <kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow key) nine times
 <kbd>`Just ̲some text`</kbd>    User presses **<kbd>Del</kbd>** four times
 <kbd>`Just ̲ text`</kbd>        User presses **<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>**
 <kbd>`Just any_text`</kbd>     User presses **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**
**Out:** `Just any text`

**In:** `Remove me`
**Allow the user to edit:**
 <kbd>`Remove me_`</kbd>        User presses **<kbd>Backspace</kbd>** nine times
 <kbd>`_`</kbd>                 User presses **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**
**Out:**  (empty string)

---

* To prevent trivial editor solutions, this must either be supplied via a different input method than the editing commands, or must be separated from them by a newline or similar.

Comment: Do we have to use those exact keypresses for i/o? Also, can we create a file to save the text to?

Comment: @Riker *key-bindings are suggestions only*. Input and output methods follow [PPCG defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

Comment: Can the string contain newlines? And can a newline be used to "submit"?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien No; *Simple **line** editor*. Yes; *The editor must at minimum allow the user to:* (...) *4. submit the new string*

Comment: It would be nice if you specified *line* in the actual body of the question, as titles on this site are not exactly specifications...

Comment: @ConorO'Brien OK?

Comment: Is it needed to respond to the `Enter` key? Or can I bind my edit control directly to a variable?

Comment: @sergiol *The line editor must at minimum allow the user to* (...) *submit the new string*. *key-bindings are suggestions only*. As long as there is a possibility for the user to signal that editing is done, it is fine.

Comment: So, Is my answer valid or not?

Comment: @sergiol Can the user click the `╳` button to stop editing and let surrounding code continue?

Comment: Clicking the X button will exit from application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57649/discussion-between-adam-and-sergiol).

Comment: A nice challenge but too vulnerable to abuse

Comment: @BetaDecay I think I've managed to patch up the worst holes. Do you see any more?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Bash, 2 bytes: `vi` (jk)

Comment: @programmer5000 How do you submit?

Comment: @programmer5000 APL, 1 byte: `∇`

Comment: I think this is one case where banning builtins would've been a good idea.

Comment: @12Me21 But *which* build-ins? Those that do the entire job? Half of it? Rather than hard-to-define bans, we need a better voting culture that promotes ingenuity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
⍞←⍞⋄⍞
```

This is a tradfn, so to use it, do

```apl
∇a
⍞←⍞⋄⍞
∇
```

And then call it by using `a`, after which you supply the starting string, and then you can edit the string.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

I don't understand why this is getting so many upvotes!

```
s=>prompt(s,s)
```

Saved a byte thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%C3%A1m)'s suggestion that I display the original input in the `prompt`.

---

### Try It

```js
f=
s=>prompt(s,s)
console.log(f("Edit this ..."))
```

Comment: Save a byte by replacing `""` with `0` or even `s` (so the user can still see the original text while editing -  a neat feature).

Answer (score 5):

## Bash 4.x, 25 characters

```bash
read -ei "$*" t
echo "$t"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ bash interactive.sh hello world
hello golfing world
hello golfing world
```

(Line 2 above was the interactive editing, line 3 the output of resulted text.)

Comment: Doesn't work, for me, `-bash: read: -i: invalid option`? `man` says only `ers` are allowed flags.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to ask about `-ei`

Comment: `-i` was introduced in Bash 4.0 (released in February 2009) – “-i text   Use TEXT as the initial text for Readline”.

Comment: I'm wondering, would cat work?

Comment: `cat` just awaits for incoming stream, for which the shell will provide no editing functionality. At least not by default.

Answer (score 4):

## C + NCURSES, 573 bytes

```C
#include <curses.h>
i;j;k;s;c;p;int main(a,b)char**b;{char*q;char t[999];if(a&&(q=b[1]))while(*q)t[s++]=*q++;i=s;initscr();noecho();keypad(stdscr,1);do{for(j=0;j<i;j++)addch(t[j]);addch('|');for(j=i;t[j];j++)addch(t[j]);c=getch();switch(c){case KEY_LEFT:if(i)i--;break;case KEY_RIGHT:if(i<s)i++;break;case 8:case 127:case KEY_BACKSPACE:if(i){for(k=i-1;k<s;k++)t[k]=t[k+1];i--;s--;}break;case KEY_DC:if(i<s){for(k=i;k<s;k++)t[k]=t[k+1];s--;}break;default:if(c>31&c<127){for(k=s;k>i;k--)t[k]=t[k-1];t[i]=c;i++;s++;}}clear();}while(c!=10);printw(t);getch();endwin();return 0;}
```

**Test**

- Compile & Run with input `Just some text`.

[image]

[image]

- Press Left-Arrow button nine times.

[image]

- Press Delete button four times.

[image]

- Press `a` then `n` then `y`.

[image]

- Press `Enter` to terminate.

[image]

**Detailed**

```C
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char*q = 0;
    char t[999] = {0};
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    int i = 0; // cursor before first char
    int s = 0; // current size
    int c = 0; // current input
    int p = 0;

    // copy first command-line argument
    if(argc>0 && (q=argv[1]))while(*q)t[s++]=*q++; i=s;

    initscr(); // initiate NCURSES
    noecho(); // input does not echo on entry
    keypad(stdscr,TRUE); // handle all input

    do
    {
        // print current content with cursor
        for(j=0;j<i;j++) addch(t[j]);
        addch('|'); for(j=i;t[j];j++) addch(t[j]);

//      printw("\n\n> key %d pressed",c); // debug

        c = getch(); // read next char

        switch(c)
        {
            case KEY_LEFT: // left arrow; cursor left
            if(i > 0) i--;
            break;

            case KEY_RIGHT: // right arrow; cursor right
            if(i < s) i++;
            break;

            case 8: // backspace; remove previous char
            case 127:
            case KEY_BACKSPACE:
            if(i > 0)
            {
                for(k=i-1; k<s; k++) t[k]=t[k+1];
                i--;s--;
            }
            break;

            case KEY_DC: // delete; remove next char
            if(i < s)
            {
                for(k=i; k<s; k++) t[k]=t[k+1];
                s--;
            }
            break;

            default: // none of the above

            if(c > 31 && c < 127) // printable char
            {
                for(k=s; k>i; k--) t[k]=t[k-1];
                t[i] = c;i++;s++;
            }
        }

        clear(); // clear screen
        if(c == 10) break;
    }
    while(c);

    addch('\n');
    printw(t); // print final result
    getch(); // wait for any input
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you replace `KEY_*`by the respective integers to save some bytes?

Answer (score 3):

## HTML + JavaScript (ES6), <strike>77 66</strike> 64 bytes

**HTML**

```
<input id=t
```

**JavaScript**

```
onkeyup=e=>e.which-13||alert(t.value);f=a=>t.value=a;
```

Saved 10 bytes thanks to Jörg Hülsermann and 2 bytes thanks to Luke.

```js
onkeyup=e=>e.which-13||alert(t.value);f=a=>t.value=a;

f("Remove Me");
```

```html
<input id=t>
```

Comment: you can remove the type attribut for the input Element

Comment: You should probably use `oninput` instead.

Comment: @SIGSEGV I don't think `oninput` fires when `Enter` is pressed

Comment: `e.which==13?alert(t.value):0` -> `e.which-13||alert(t.value)` saves two bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + Vi/Vim, 14 bytes

```
echo $1>a;vi a
```

`vi` is aliased to `vim` on macOS, I don't know about other OSes.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but does this meet the requirement of outputting the modified string?

Comment: @GraysonKent you can save and quit by hitting `:wq!` or `:x`, so I think so. OP is a bit unclear on what qualifies as that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>275</s> 200 bytes

Not a winner, but here it is:

```python
from msvcrt import*
s=list(input())[::-1]
c=i=0
def p(a):print''.join(a)[::-1]
while'\r'!=c:p(s[:i]+['<']+s[i:]);c=getch();x=c!='\b';exec["s[i:i+1-x]=c*x","i=(i-1+2*(c<'\\t'))%-~len(s)"][x*' '>c]
p(s)
```

### Explanation:

It works by reversing the input (with `[::-1]`), and excluding and inserting characters in that reversed input so that the cursor does not have to move. Reverses it again when printing.

### Usage:

[Tab] key to move Right
[Ctrl+C] to move Left
[Backspace] to erase
[Return] to finish editing
Any other key, will be inserted into text

### Example:

Using OP's example

**In:** `Just some text`
 <kbd>`Just some text>`</kbd>
 <kbd>`Just some> text`</kbd> User presses **<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>** five times
 <kbd>`Just > text`</kbd>     User presses **<kbd>Backspace</kbd>** four times
 <kbd>`Just any> text`</kbd>  User presses **<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>**
 
 <kbd>`Just any> text`</kbd>  User presses **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**
**Out:** `Just any text`

### Inline editor version:

If you want the text to be editted inline, append `,'\r',` at the end of the `print` statement:

```python
def p(a):print''.join(a)[::-1],'\r',
```

Comment: +1 Very nice. First answer which actually implements a real editor, as opposed to relying on pre-existing functionality. I was considering posting another challenge to do just this.

Comment: Can't you save bytes by using other keys for left and right?

Comment: I could assume characters as `-` and `+` to do so, but the editor would be unable to accept those characters then

Comment: How about `\t` and `\v`?

Comment: how do i use `\v`? ctrl+v?

Comment: That's the user's problem, no? Control+K, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

### VBScript, <s>23</s> 40 bytes

```
MsgBox InputBox("",,Wscript.Arguments(0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>9</s> <s>19</s> <s>22</s> 84 bytes

```
->s{r=Readline;r.pre_input_hook=->{r.insert_text s;r.redisplay};r.readline}
```

This creates a Readline pre input hook that inserts the text s and then redisplays. After this, irb gets messed up so make sure to run this from a file. Run as a lambda, it takes the input string as an argument and returns the output string.

```
puts Readline.readline
```

This uses the Readline library to perform line editing. My previous answer only allowed backspaces.

```
puts gets
```

This is really, *really* self explanatory.

Edit: I have been asked for an explanation. This is equivalent to `puts(gets)`. `gets` inputs a string with a line editor. `puts` outputs it.

Comment: Chain the method calls: `r.insert_text(s).redisplay` and remove the following `;`. BTW, as I understand our policy, you should mention that your code runs in `irb`, because otherwise you would need to require `Readline` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 53 bytes

```
s=>{SendKeys.SendWait(s);return Console.ReadLine();};
```

Where `s` is a string to modify and the output is the new value.

[SendKeys.SendWait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait(v=vs.110).aspx): Sends the given keys to the active application, and then waits for the messages to be processed.

or 74 bytes if we are not in a Windows Forms context:

```
s=>{System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(s);return Console.ReadLine();};
```

[image: gif demo]

Answer (score 1):

## PHP + HTML, 26 Bytes

```
<input value=<?=$_GET[0]?>
```

The Browser adds automatically the closing tag

[$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) Using a url like `http://example.com?0=input` as Input 
Creates in a HTML `<input value=input`

And this is the output for the string input

```html
<input value=input
```

Comment: Should I assume this works? Maybe you can add an explanation, or link, or animation?

Comment: @Adám Yes you can assume this Maybe you will it improve and set the attribute `autofocus` to have the cursor at the beginning in it. Other HTML elements you can also edit if you set the attribute `contenteditable`

Comment: Input = `test></input><script>alert("Hi");//some malicious code\n</script>`

Comment: @RomanGräf Bad Boy. Yes it is better to filter Javascript

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl, 17

```
puts [gets stdin]
```

Online interpreters just suck to demonstrate it, then I showcase some images from a Windows command shell:

## Test case 1

[image][image][image][image][image]

## Test case 2

[image][image] [image]

Comment: Can you explain this one?

Comment: I can add images of it running on a Windows command line.

Comment: @Adám: Do you still want me to explain what the code is doing or are the images enough?

Comment: This is enough.

Answer (score 1):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 32 bytes

```
InputBox,s,,,,,,,,,,%1%
Send,%s%
```

`InputBox` stores whatever is typed as the variable `s` and gives a starting prompt of the variable `1` which is the first passed parameter.
`Send` sends keystrokes to the current window. In this case, it'll be the contents of `s`.
`MsgBox` was an option but, for golfing, `Send` is 2 bytes shorter.

[image: Animation]

Comment: @Adám I misread that part. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Now it is good.

Answer (score 1):

### Excel VBA Immediate Window Command - 22 bytes

```
[a1]=inputbox(0,,[a1])
```

[image]

Comment: This is only a partial solution, as your initial value ("Hi") is hard-coded. The initial value must be read from somewhere (a cell or a prompt or a file...) and the final value must be put somewhere (a cell, a messagebox, a file,...).

Comment: `inputbox(0,,"Hi")` saves a byte

Comment: @Adám Thanks. Fixed now it's reading from cell A1

Comment: I think you need `[a1]=inputbox(0,,[a1])` or something, otherwise, where does `a` go? [Storing in a variable is not a valid output method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6965/43319).

Comment: It goes where it came from cell A1

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 138 bytes

```
DEF E S@L
WAIT
B=BUTTON(1)C=C-(B==4&&C)+(B>7&&C<LEN(S))I$=INKEY$()IF"\u0008"<I$THEN B=I$<"\u000E"S=SUBST$(S,C,B,I$*!B)?S?" "*C;1IF"\u0008"!=I$GOTO@L
END
```

Creates a function `E` with 1 argument and 0 outputs. (Output is displayed in the console)

The escaped characters should be the actual symbols, but they wouldn't show up here.

Controls:

```
Normal keys: Insert a character before the cursor.
Enter: Delete the character at the cursor.
Backspace: Submit.
D-pad left: Move cursor left.
All buttons except up, down, and left on the d-pad: Move cursor right.
```

Inserting/deleting characters is backwards so it's very annoying to use (but should still fulfill the requirements).

```
Just some text
1             
'(press right 5 times)
Just some text
     1
'(press enter 4 times)
Just  text
     1
'(press a)
Just a text
     1
'(press right)
Just a text
      1
'(...)
Just any text
       1
'(press backspace)
```

Answer (score 0):

## ZX Spectrum BASIC, 7 bytes

Trivial, included for completeness (`INPUT` and `PRINT` are one byte tokens each).

```
INPUT a$: PRINT a$
```

Comment: How does it get the initial value of `a$`?

Comment: @Adám it gets the initial value of `a$` by keyboard input; `a$` will be over-written with the `INPUT` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows command interpreter, 16 bytes

```
set/pa=
echo %a%
```

This is very trivial; the command interpreter is trivially a "line editor".

Answer (score 0):

## Commodore BASIC (C64Mini, C64/128, VIC-20 etc...) 179 tokenized BASIC bytes

This should be typed in business mode (upper/lower case characters)

```
 0a$="Just some text":?"{SHIFT+CLR/HOME}"a$"_":fOi=0to1step0:getk$:on-(k$<>"")goS2:goS1:nE
 1?"{CTRL+N}{CLR/HOME}"a$"_  ";:return
 2ifasc(k$)<>20thena$=a$+k$:on-(asc(k$)=13)goS4:return
 3if-(len(a$))thena$=leF(a$,len(a$)-1):goS4:return
 4?"{ARROW LEFT}{ARROW LEFT}{ARROW LEFT}  ":return
```

Allows basic text editing + delete + new line. Maximum size of `a$` like all strings in Commodore BASIC is 255 characters, so any more than that will crash the program. I will find a way to do > 255 characters if that is necessary.

[image: Simple type-em-up simulator]

[image: Simple type-em-up simulator in action]